# Error/Exception handling in GraphqlExpress

Tags: node.js, webstorm, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm new to GraphQL and using graphqlExpress in my nodejs project.

```
const buildOptions = async (req, res) => {
    const user = await authenticate(req, mongo.Users);
    return {
        formatError,
        schema,
        context: {dataloaders: buildDataloaders(mongo),mongo, user}, // This context object is passed to all resolvers.
    };
};

app.use('/api', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress(buildOptions));
```

Resolver methods for Query, Mutations are implemented, but when I throw an Error object from any of the resolver methods then the error is not handled by graphqlExpress and node process is crashing. On debugging it stops at 'emitDestroyScript' method in async_hooks.js file of nodejs.

[image: debug callstack]

Any help to appreciated to address this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Same for me when debugging on webstorm create-react-app's Jest tests, it always stops at function emitDestroyScript(asyncId) declaration in async-hooks.js file